# Tableau API 500 Error - showExportImageDialog()

Tags: javascript, image, pdf, export, tableau-api

I am currently trying to use the Tableau Javascript API to export a dashboard to Image. I am using the viz.showExportImageDialog() function found in the documentation- https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_ref.htm.
I have verified that my viz is properly initialized. For some reason I am getting a 500 error. I know my server is okay because I load in the viz just before attempting to export it and I get no errors, and when I log my viz to the console it is showing up as it should. Here is my code-

```
viz: null,
options: {
    hideTabs: true,
    height: 0,
    width: 0
},
```

And then in my function I do this-

```
let url = `${process.env.TAB_SERVER_ADDRESS}trusted/${data}/views/${vm.csv.tableauViewPath}?:render=false`
this.viz = new tableau.Viz(
    document.getElementById('csv-view-instance'),
    url,
    this.options
)
```

I then do this in another function (triggered by a click)-

```
console.log(this.viz)
try {
  this.viz.showExportImageDialog()
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

The console.log of the viz shows exactly what I would expect. I am pretty new to this, does anyone know why I am getting a 500 error? Let me know if you need more details. Thanks in advance!